# How to sort on two fields of numbers

Tags: ksh, sort

I have a list of filename like so:

```
epdb_0_0.pdb
epdb_0_10.pdb
epdb_0_11.pdb
epdb_0_12.pdb
epdb_0_13.pdb
epdb_0_14.pdb
epdb_0_15.pdb
epdb_0_16.pdb
epdb_0_17.pdb
epdb_0_18.pdb
epdb_0_19.pdb
epdb_0_1.pdb
epdb_0_20.pdb
epdb_0_21.pdb
epdb_0_22.pdb
epdb_0_23.pdb
epdb_0_24.pdb
epdb_0_25.pdb
epdb_0_26.pdb
epdb_0_27.pdb
epdb_0_28.pdb
epdb_0_29.pdb
epdb_0_2.pdb
epdb_0_30.pdb
...
```

How do I use the Unix sort command to get the list to look like:

```
epdb_0_0.pdb
epdb_0_1.pdb
epdb_0_2.pdb
...
epdb_0_10.pdb
epdb_0_11.pdb
epdb_0_12.pdb
epdb_0_13.pdb
epdb_0_14.pdb
epdb_0_15.pdb
epdb_0_16.pdb
epdb_0_17.pdb
...
epdb_1_0.pdb
epdb_1_2.pdb
epdb_1_3.pdb
...
```

I know it's some sort of useage of the `--key= flag`, possibly in combination `iwht -n or -g`, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sort -t "_" -k2 -k3 -g <filename>
```

`-t "_"` - field seperator is `_`

`-k2` - 1st sort on the second column

`-k3` - then sort on the third column

`-g` - general numerical sort

Comment: Gives
epdb_0_0.pdb
epdb_1_0.pdb
epdb_0_1.pdb
epdb_1_1.pdb
epdb_0_2.pdb
epdb_1_2.pdb
epdb_0_3.pdb


I want 
epdb_0_0.pdb
epdb_0_1.pdb
epdb_0_2.pdb
epdb_0_3.pdb
epdb_0_4.pdb
...
epdb_1_0.pdb
epdb_1_2.pdb
epdb_1_3.pdb
... etc

Comment: To be fair, the first numerical column is all zeros in your question; so the output you requested is provided by this command. However, the wording of your question does say 'two fields' I suppose :-o It's a simple change, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: Yes that's true, I should have added more in my example list. But maybe you could tell me how I stop the forum removing all my newlines?

Comment: There is [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments), but it's quite basic. Quite often it's easier to edit the question, especially for showing code.  It also helps future readers as people tend to read the question and answers, but not comments.  For example, you could edit the question to state that *you don't need:* (add example of incorrect output), then add a comment to the answers (mine in this case) to ask me to look at the question again as it's changed slightly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to sorting a list of filenames in a particular way, you could just use:

```
ls -1v *.pdb
```

to list the files in the required order in first place.

Answer (score 1):

Can do like this :

```
$ cat file.txt | sort -t"_" | sort -n -k3 -t"_"
```

- file.txt contain the first list not sorted.

Cheers.

Comment: You can eliminate first sort command.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sort -t_ -k3n
```

- `-t_`: sets field separator to `_`
- `-k3n`: sorts on `3`rd field numerically (`n`)

Comment: Gives:
epdb_0_0.pdb
epdb_1_0.pdb
epdb_0_1.pdb
epdb_1_1.pdb
epdb_0_2.pdb
epdb_1_2.pdb

not what I'm after

Comment: BTW how do I stop the forum removing all my newlines?

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -V
```

> -V, --version-sort
>   *natural sort of (version) numbers within text*

Comment: `ls -1 epdb*.pdb | sort -V *.pdb 
sort: invalid option -- V
Try `sort --help' for more information.`

Comment: @Doug97 `sort --version` : *sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21* Please choice what you want to sort `ls -v1 epdb*.pdb` or `sort -V file_list`

Comment: sort -V throws the invalid option error whichever ... also it doesn't appear in my sort's manpage